# Strange OptionsMenu display in 4.3

Tags: android, android-layout

I have code that has worked fine since 1.6 suddenly not displaying properly after upgrade to 4.3.

It looks like the system that paints the menu gets the wrong value for screen width.

Any ideas the code is tested! I tried changing Themes I am out of ideas!

It appears to affect only 4.x devices. All other devices are unaffected.

In onCreate have the required:-

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>10)
     getActionBar();
```

also

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     if (!app().day_change){
         menu.add(0,0,0,"<<Day");
         menu.add(0,1,0,"Day>>");
     }
     menu.add(0,2,0,"Hot Sync");
     menu.add(0,3,0,"Delete Week File");
     menu.add(0,4,0,"Import Test Data File");
     menu.add(0,5,0,"View Mod History");
     menu.add(0,15,0,"View Changes to Data");
     menu.add(0,6,0,"Select Bluetooth device");
     menu.add(0,9,0,"View Auto Backup files");
     menu.add(0,10,0,"Options");
     //menu.add(0,7,0,"WIFI Print Test");
     //menu.add(0,8,0,"Delnote Test");
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
         menu.clear();
         if (!app().day_change){
             menu.add(0,0,0,"<<Day");
             menu.add(0,1,0,"Day>>");
         }
         menu.add(0,2,0,"Hot Sync");
         menu.add(0,3,0,"Delete Week File");
         menu.add(0,4,0,"Import Test Data File");
         menu.add(0,5,0,"View Mod History");
         menu.add(0,15,0,"View Changes to Data");
         menu.add(0,6,0,"Select Bluetooth device");
         menu.add(0,9,0,"View Auto Backup files");
         menu.add(0,10,0,"Options");
         menu.add(0,11,0,"SMS Invoicing");
         
         subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Contacts");
         subMenu.add(0, 12, 0, "  Update");
         subMenu.add(0, 13, 0, "  Delete All z");
         menu.add(0,14,0,"Email Steve Weekfile");

         //menu.add(0,7,0,"WIFI Print Test");
         //menu.add(0,8,0,"Delnote Test");
         return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Here's the view from a Nexus 7

[image: Option menu]
<sub>(source: [milkroundsoftware.co.uk](http://www.milkroundsoftware.co.uk/device-2013-08-12-094853.png))</sub>

Many Thanks Steve

Comment: If I am not posting this in the right place where should I post it?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use the onPrepareOptionsMenu .

instead, add items to the menu in case it's empty, and always return true in the onCreateOptionsMenu() method.

also, if you wish to handle the actionBar on old devices, consider using [actionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

Comment: I removed the onPrepareOtionsMenu and returned true in onCreateOptionsMenu ....still got the same result???       I am not bothered about having ActionBar on older devices.

Comment: ok, let's try a simpler thing. try to add only 6 items to the menu, just titles : menu.add("item 0"); , menu.add("item 1");  , and so on. tell us what you see.

Comment: Basically the same I get 6 menus displayed upto the "m" in Item I don't see the " 0"

Comment: changed oncresteOptionsMenu to   menu.add("Item 0");
            menu.add("Item 1");
            menu.add("Item 2");
            menu.add("Item 3");
            menu.add("Item 4");
            menu.add("Item 5");
            return true; same result didn't see any numbers

Comment: ok then. can you please show me the relevant code , the minimal one that causes the problem. better create a totally new project with this problem alone. don't forget to set the targetSdk to the max available (18) and same for the project.properties file.

Comment: what ? i don't understand. in the previous post you wrote that it didn't work... please tell me what is the difference so that i could tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I created a new project and have built it with the same layout.xml file as the one shown above and menu works ok so where should I look now???

Comment: have you tried checking the manifest and the project.properties of your old project? check what i've written to you to update (targetSdk).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be simple in the Manifest

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

android:anyDensity was set to false it resulted (as a side effect perhaps) that when the menu was rendered the width variable was set to zero hence the resulting position on the screen.

Thanks for your help anyway - should I flag this as an issue??